# scrollHeight for readonly textarea

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a form results page where I'm using a readonly textarea to display the email address that's been submitted. I'm trying to make the textarea grow in height to fit the email displayed. So far I've only been able to display it truncated.

[image: Form Results]

I'm trying to do this as simply as possible, as the email field character limit is 254.

My jQuery is a work in progress, but here's what I've written:

```
$("textarea").each( function( i, el ) {
    $(el).height( el.scrollHeight );
});
```

...and the HTML

```
<textarea class="created" id="email_address" name="email_address" value="" readonly=""></textarea>
```

...and CSS

```
textarea {
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 28px;
  resize: none;
  height: 37.5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: transparent;
 }
```

Comment: The posted imge on imgur fails. Then, Trying to recreate using the posted code... I see no issue. By the way, `readonly` is a boolean attribute, when it's present, it's true, absent, it's false.

Comment: Your issue is one of the 2 scenarios: 1) the function runs before the emails are appended to the textarea. 2) the function runs before the textarea exists in DOM.

Comment: I moved the script from an external js file to the body of the results page to see if I could get the script to run after and still no joy. I'm not married to using a textarea, if there is something that will work better.

Comment: Good test. I don't think the issue is tied to the element itself. I've made a quick [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/XBoJWJ?editors=1111) to show the possible "timing" issue. -- Now, I reread your question. I suppose the textarea only is to display the email address (not the whole message) in the image you posted...  I suddenly have a "diviner" feeling that you possibly wish a "super long email" to auto wrap on multiple lines... Would it be it?

Comment: Am I close it, reproducing your issue, with this second [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KBbwjV?editors=1111)?

Comment: yes, this is what I'm after. I'm thinking that there's another script that might be manipulating the textarea in my document. Unfortunately, this is part of a greater page and scripts sometimes overlap.

Comment: after further inspecting your second codepen, this is exactly the issue i'm running into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you dynamically append the email address to the `textarea`... It may be on success of an Ajax request **or** just an `.append()`.

You obviously run the height adjustement function **before** the content is appended.

You agreed that this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KBbwjV?editors=1111) is real close to your issue.

And the below snippet is a solution.

```js
swal({
  title: "Username Has Been Sent.",
  type: "success",
  html: "Didn't receive the email?<br>"+
  "<a href='#'>Resend Email</a><br>"+
  "<br>"+
  "Information Provided: <a href='#'>Edit</a><br>"+
  "<br>"+
  "<small>Email address:</small><br>"+
  "<textarea class='created' id='email_address' name='email_address' readonly></textarea>",
  showConfirmButton: false
})

// Make it a named function
function adjustTextareaHeight(){
  $("textarea").each( function( i, el ) {
    $(el).height( el.scrollHeight );
    console.log("Textarea height adjusted to content.");
  });
  
  // OR if there's only one textarea:
  // $("#email_address").height( this.scrollHeight );
}

// To simulate an Ajax request:
var email = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890@super-long-domain-name-impossible-to-remember-for-a-normal-human-being.com";
$("#email_address").append(email);

// In the callback of an Ajax request... Or right after the appending (like here):
adjustTextareaHeight();
```

```css
textarea {
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 28px;
  resize: none;
  height: 37.5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: transparent;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.26.10/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.26.10/sweetalert2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: this is solid...it works here but the when i visit the CodePen, the email address is truncated.